# Merge [unet], [unity-networking], and [unity3d-unet]

Tags: discussion

Tag description for [unet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unet) (2 followers, 58 questions):

> UNET is short form of unity networking .Use this tag to ask question related to Unity3d networking.

Tag description for [unity3d-unet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d-unet) (21 followers, 116 questions):

> UNET is the native Unity3D network system.

Tag descriptiomn for [unity-networking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity-networking) (11 followers, 133 questions):

> Unity 5.1 introduced a new framework to handle client+server networking, also known as UNet.

All of these tags are describing the same thing and many questions are tagged with more than one (a single question is tagged with all three).

These should *not* be burninated and replaced with [unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity)+[networking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/networking) as there are many ways of doing networking in Unity, *one of which* is UNet (a specific implementation, built into the Unity engine), another is [photon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/photon).

I suggest making the primary tag [unet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unet) (similar to [photon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/photon)) with the other two as synonyms.

Comment: I believe [unity-networking] to be the most descriptive of the three. It's apparent from just the tag name what it's about without being overly specific. If we're merging, I think that should be the primary tag.

Comment: @AfroThundr I am not opposed to this, I was actually debating with myself over which I preferred.

Comment: @AfroThundr The problem with that tag name is that the technology in question is actually called UNet (if I am reading the post correctly). Is UNet a *component* of Unity or a completely separate technology that *depends on* Unity? If it's a component, [tag:unity3d-unet] is the only one of the three that includes the proper names of both the parent technology and the component. If it's a separate technology, then I'm more inclined to your original suggestion of keeping [tag:unet].

Comment: Although, given these tags low usage (less than 300 questions total vs. nearly 30,000 [tag:unity] questions), do we *really* need tags for this? There are likely dozens to hundreds of questions about this technology that aren't tagged with it. If it's a third party technology and/or people who specifically maintain or heavily user it follow the tag(s), then I agree it makes sense to keep them around, but editors should be editing it onto applicable questions if so. The number of followers seems high, but the percentage of unanswered questions is also high (77% for unet).

Comment: Complete aside, I'm no longer able to find the number of followers for a tag anywhere. How did you get them?

Comment: @jpmc26 If you hover over it when it's tagged on a question, it'll show the numbers. I think it's somewhere else too, not sure. As for how many questions it has, it's a fairly new addition to Unity; it deserves its own tag IMO because it operates on some black box magic (packets are hidden from the developer), so its worth having it as a separate tag. That said, if someone says it should be burninated, they're free to start that process if they like.

Comment: @Draco18s Unity 5.1 was introduced almost exactly 3 years ago, how is that fairly new?

Comment: I'd suggest keeping [tag:unity3d-unet] and renaming [tag:photon] to [tag:unity3d-photon]

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Photon isn't just Unity, it supports [multiple platforms](https://www.photonengine.com/en-US/Photon), including Unreal 4.